# object projection returns error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

when I try to return object from projection, it gets errored or returns wrong value (which I don't want to get).

For example my query object is

```
 object = {
  name: {
            "eng" : foo ,
            "rus": bar
   };
};
```

I want to return from this object

```
 object = {
  name: foo
};
```

What I've tried so far is -

```
model.find(query,{'name.eng': 1},function ...
```

Comment: Try aggregation. Do a match phase first and then use the project phase. model.aggregate([{<-match->},{"$project":{"_id":"$_id","english":"$name.eng"}}])

Comment: I know this, but isn't it possible without aggregation framework?

Comment: Should be. I tried it on a test collection that had nested objects and got this query to work - db.tests.find({},{"a.t":1})

Comment: @IshanSoni i tried this, but return object like this  

`object = { name: {'eng':'foo'} }; `

Comment: Yes it will return that since that is the matched document. If you want to convert it into the document you require you will have to use the project phase.